# el nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres xamarin no se encontro

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Estoy tratando de comenzar una app en Visual Studio 2017 y Xamarin, cuando ingreso al App.xaml.cs, me lanza este error **el nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres xamarin no se encontro** en varios puntos, a lo mejor tengo que instalar algo más.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Has instalado Xamarin? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/installation/windows

Comment: Si, tengo instalado Xamarin

Comment: Prueba a seleccionar la solución > Botón derecho > "Administrar paquetes Nuget..." > busca xamarin.forms y mira si está instalado.

Comment: Volví a instalar todo nuevamente y me sigue lanzando el mismo error. Error CS0400

Comment: Aquí dan varias soluciones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994273/the-type-or-namespace-name-xamarin-missing-in-xamarin-studio

Answer (score 2):

Yo tuve el mismo error y solo con actualizar xamarin.forms en el paquede NuGet
se corrigio.
En referencias da click derecho y selecciona, administrar paquetes NuGet, busca xamarin.forms, das click y le das actualizar

Comment: Tu respuesta puede mejorarse, te recomiendo que revises el siguiente artículo: [Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

En las referencias se hace click derecho y selecciona, se administran paquetes NuGet, busca `xamarin.forms`, das click y le da das actualiza. Tuve el mismo error y solo con actualizar `xamarin.forms` in the paquede NuGet quedó corregido.

Comment: Hola Ketanima, sería de gran ayuda para la persona que está preguntando que puedas ofrecer mucha más información para ayudarla con su problema, prueba con incluir código, pantallazos, detallar un poco más el problema, y así tu respuesta será mucho más aceptada por la comunidad

Comment: Esta respuesta parece una copia de la respuesta dada hace mas de un año. Que aporta de diferente?